# Como referenciar mat[x][y] em notação de ponteiros

Tags: c, ponteiro, alocação

Estou trabalhando com *programação em c*, expecificamente com ponteiros e alocação dinâmica, preciso responder a um exercicio que pede o seguinte:

> Como referenciar mat[x][y] em notação de ponteiros.

Comment: Como você alocou a matriz?

Comment: Nunca trabalhei bem com matriz, mas geralmente com vetores faço o seguinte:                                                                                       
 vetor = (int *)malloc(10 * sizeof(int));
 if (vetor == NULL) {
  printf("Nao consegui ALOCAR MEMORIA.\n");
  return -1;   
 }

Comment: Então você a aloca linearmente como um vetor?

Comment: Isso, creio que o exercicio esta me pedindo é para fazer o mesmo, porém agora com um vetor de vetores, isso que não entendi bem ao certo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vetores de vetores com alocação dinâmica, são basicamente *jagged arrays*.

O vetor inicial passará a ser um vetor de ponteiros, apontando cada uma das suas casas para outro vetor. A figura seguinte ilustra bem este conceito:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isto faz com que a matriz tenha que ser definida como um ponteiro para ponteiro:

```
int **matriz = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10); //10 linhas
```

Para cada uma das linhas definidas é necessário criar o respetivo vetor com a quantidade de colunas através de um laço/ciclo:

```
int i;
for (i = 0; i <10; ++i){
    matriz[i] = malloc(sizeof(int)*10); //cada linha tem 10 colunas
}
```

Após isto temos uma matriz 10 por 10 que foi alocada dinamicamente. Esta pode agora ser utilizada normalmente como uma que tivesse sido alocada estaticamente.

**Liberação de memória**

Lembre-se também que uma vez que foi alocada dinamicamente é você o responsável por a desalocar quando não precisar dela invocando o `free`. Isso será talvez mais elaborado do que pensa uma vez que tem que desalocar primeiro os sub-vetores e depois a matriz principal:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
    free(matriz[i]);
}

free(matriz);
```